# Running one solr server with multiple configsets?

Tags: solr, typo3

As we use one solr server for multiple TYPO3 instances, on different upgrade levels we're interested in running multiple configsets in one server.

Based on the TYPO3 extension `solr` I tried to connect one TYPO3 instance with `ext:solr` updated to 11.0.3 with a solr server configured with a configset from `ext:solr` 10.0.3.
That resulted in errors and I had to fallback to `ext:solr` 10.0.3.

Then I tried to enhance the solr configuration with another configset and additional core definitions, but the 'new' cores are not visible anywhere.

I tried it with this files and folders (only one language shown here):

```
server/
:
+-solr/
| +-configsets/
| | +-ext_solr_10_0_0
| | : +- ...
| | +-ext_solr_11_0_0
| |   +- ...
| +-cores/
| | +-english/
| | : +-core.properties
| |   +-core11.properties
: :
```

having the original `core.properties` from `ext:solr` 10

```
configSet=ext_solr_10_0_0
schema=english/schema.xml
name=core_en
dataDir=../../data/english
```

and the modified `core11.properties` from `ext:solr` 11, which I expected to add a `core_en_11` to the list of cores

```
configSet=ext_solr_11_0_0
schema=english/schema.xml
name=core_en_11
dataDir=../../data/english
```

is it possible to have multiple configsets with different cores?
and how can I configure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not possible to have multiple configuration in one folder. Or other names than `core.properties` are not evaluated?

Changing the structure to:

```
server/
:
+-solr/
| +-configsets/
| | +-ext_solr_10_0_0
| | : +- ...
| | +-ext_solr_11_0_0
| |   +- ...
| +-cores/
| | +-english/
| | | +-core.properties
| | +-english_11/
| | : +-core.properties
: :
```

added additional core(s) identified by the name in the file(s) `core.properties`

I also have changed the data folder to `dataDir=../../data/english_11`, but I 'm not sure if this is really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
the dataDir must be different.